# can't send emails on android 3.2

Tags: android

I tried this [link](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) to send an email via Android 3.2, but I got this error :

```
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): Could not send email
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:371)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at com.fahadalawam.kwtresturant.Mail.send(Mail.java:125)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at com.fahadalawam.kwtresturant.Add$1.onClick(Add.java:58)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-11 13:48:59.818: E/MailApp(29958): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

There's your answer right there. You're trying to access the network in the main UI thread. This is bad! See [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for guidance on how to avoid it.

The article you linked to is setting a bad example by calling the `send()` method in a click handler. You may want to contact the author of that page to point out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a network related operation on main thread!! Android 3.0 onwards don't allow this at all as a step towards making better behaved and responsive applications( The older versions just gave a warning) . See this line in your stackTrace

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

So, you need to push the email sending part off the main thread. In the example you are following, there is no need for an AsyncTask, a simple Thread will do.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
              // send email 
                    Transport.send(msg); 

        }
    };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
```